# Imagick don't open pdf files with "Failed to read the file" exception

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagick, php-7

Trying to open PDF file from php script drop into fault with error:

```
Uncaught ImagickException: Failed to read the file in ...
```

I'm running OS X, Brew, PHP 7.0, php70-imagick --HEAD, ImageMagick --with-ghostscript, GhostScript

Command line test works fine:

```
convert 1.pdf 1.jpg
```

File permission is ok. Try both, an URL and local file with realpath function, so filepath is ok too. Script works fine if open jpeg.

```
phpinfo() -> ImageMagick supported formats: EPDF, PDF, PDFA, etc.
```

UPDATE: Solved. Solution below.

Comment: And where is this PHP script? Would you show us?

Comment: Hope, it's help you: $im = new Imagick(realpath('1.pdf'));

Comment: show the output of `var_dump(realpath('1.pdf'));` please.

Comment: @Danak, string(32) "/Users/username/Sites/test/1.pdf"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413. You may need to edit your policy.xml file. Alternately, you may need to put the full path to Ghostscript (gs) in the delegates.xml file for PDF/PS/EPS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This problem was with path to ghostscript. It's locate in "/usr/local/bin", but this path is not available to Apache. (phpinfo -> Apache Environment -> PATH)

Solution is to symlink file to another path:

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs
```

OS X El Capitan Note! /usr/bin/ in OS X 10.11+ is protected. You have to follow this steps:

```
1. Reboot to Recovery Mode. Reboot and hold "Cmd + R" after start sound.
2. In Recovery Mode go to Utilities -> Terminal.
3. Run: csrutil disable
4. Reboot in Normal Mode.
5. Do the "sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs" in terminal.
6. Do the 1 and 2 step. In terminal enable back csrutil by run: csrutil enable
```

Comment: I'm stuck at this for the last three hours. Why don't they say "Ghostscript not found"?

Comment: If you've done this and hit the error `/usr/bin/gs: Read-only file system` then make sure you run `sudo mount -uw /` before you run `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs` in the steps (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480473/how-to-solve-read-only-file-system-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an better way of updating the Apache path variable on OS X which doesn't require symlinking (and therefore no need to disable SIP):

https://www.euperia.com/wrote/solved-php-imagick-unable-to-open-image-pdf/

Comment: That link has changed and is now available at:
https://www.euperia.com/wrote/solved-php-imagick-unable-to-open-image-pdf/