# How to solve Read-only file system problem?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I've upgraded to the latest OS on MAC (Catalina), but now I have problem with `virtualenv`, `python` and `django`.

When I do `source ve37/bin/activate` it's fine, but when I then do `python manage.py runserver` I get error as follow **OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/data'**

**The full error is as follows:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/Autralis/Autralis/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/Autralis/Autralis/celery.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Autralis import settings
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/Autralis/Autralis/settings.py", line 431, in <module>
    os.makedirs(GENERATED_ROOT)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/my_project/ve37/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/data'
```

Yesterday, before updating everything worked fine.

Any idea?

Comment: refer this https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/209

Comment: You've probably tried this already but still, `sudo chown -R $USER *`

Comment: @Sahil I've tried it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @c.grey I saw that post already but it didn't help.

Comment: Please share your `celery.py` code, especially `line 4`.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem because of Read-only file system in mac os catalina**

1. Boot your mac system into recovery mode. 
   (by bootup system with holding CMD+R).
2. Open terminal (Present in "Utilities" in the top left menu).
3. Just run command

   csrutil disable
4. Restart your system and Bootup normally
5. Before doing any activity open terminal and run command.

   sudo mount -uw /

Comment: I'm just trying to upgrade Python 2.7 to 3.8 and `sudo mount -uw /` solved my issue when I tried to update symbolic link and I was getting: `rm: /usr/bin/python: Read-only file system`

Comment: Many thanks, this works for me when trying to `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/git/`